# Best way to overwride all target="_blank" to open links on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to change all href links on a page to open on the same tab (target_self) instead of target blank.
Constraints: unable to access the code due to restrictions, and need a way to override all links to open in the same page, rather than on a new page.

Have tried the following

```
var otherWindow = window.open();
otherWindow.opener = null;
```

and

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr('target');
});
```

is there a way to target all links? or perhaps

Comment: With .each I always use function(i,element) ... maybe try $(element).attr({'target':'_self'}) ... use browser inspector to see if your jquery worked

Comment: _"unable to access the code"_ and _"need a way to override all links"_ seem to be at odds unless you're writing a browser extension / user script. Where _can_ you write code?

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick jQuery binds the element to `this` so OP's code should be fine

Comment: There's no need for `.each`. `removeAttr()` will automatically operate on all the selected elements. `$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target')`

Comment: Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uL5g98na/3/ If it doesn't work in your application, something else must be opening the new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working for me.

Please try it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[target="_blank"]').prop("target", "_self");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem was - the code can only be added via a widget, which was being added in the header tag, and the document.ready helped solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.
Try this https://jsfiddle.net/4wLq7k8x/1/

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
```

```js
$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Google</a> (target=_blank)<br>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="new">Yahoo</a> (target=new)
```